# Access HTML TextArea data with JavaScript in real time to find and change data being typed in real-time

Tags: javascript, textarea

I am writing an html page with a form to collect textarea data.  As I type, I would like for a JavaScript program to watch for special characters such as "\n - newline", a "\t-tab", or other items I am watching for and change the text in the textarea immediately.  I got it partially working with the textfield.value function.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please share the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an onChange or onInput event listener to the text area.. Whenever there is a change in the value of the text area, the function passed to the listener is fired

Answer (score 0):

Add `onChange` or `onInput` event listener. That's how you can do it.

```
let textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");

textarea.addEventLisenter("input", e => {
 // Text in your textarea;
 let value = e.target.value; 
 // to change your text area input
 let newValue = e.target.value.replace(/some regex/, "new value");
 e.target.value = newValue;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add InputEvent handler to the text area.

```
let textArea = document.getElementById("the-id");
textarea.addEventListener("input",event=>{
   let newText = event.data;
    swicth(newText){
     case "'\n" : {
     /* Your logic here */
     }
}
});
```